# Editing an NSPredicate using NSPredicateEditor

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nspredicate, nspredicateeditor

I can create an NSPredicate easily using an NSPredicateEditor (a subclass of NSRuleEditor).  What I'd like to know is this:

How can I take an existing NSPredicate (one created by the editor) and reload it into the editor so that I can alter it?

EDIT: I tried @John's suggestion of using setObjectValue:, but that didn't quite work.  Let me explain my set up a bit more:

I've got a Document-based cocoa app, and the Document window just has an NSPredicateEditor on it.  In the `dataOfType:error:` method, I have:

```
NSPredicate * pred = [predicateEditor objectValue];
NSData * predicateData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:pred];
return predicateData;
```

In the `readFromData:ofType:error:` method, I have:

```
NSPredicate * pred = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data];
[predicateEditor setObjectValue:pred];
return (pred != nil);
```

I've verified that the predicate is getting correctly archived and unarchived, but after opening a saved predicate, the predicate is not loaded into the predicateEditor.  (Yes, predicateEditor is hooked up as an IBOutlet)

Comment: Are you using custom templates?

Comment: @John no I just dragged and dropped a PredicateEditor from the IB Library.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Set the `objectValue` property of the `NSPredicateEditor` to the predicate in question.

The [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSPredicateEditorRowTemplate_class/Reference/NSPredicateEditorRowTemplate.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004605-CH1-DontLinkElementID_1) has this description of the loading process; does any of this seem like it might cause a problem with your setup?

> First, an instance of
>   NSPredicateEditor is created, and some
>   row templates are set on it—either
>   through a nib file or
>   programmatically. The first thing
>   predicate editor does is ask each of
>   the templates for their views, using
>   templateViews.
>
> After setting up the predicate editor,
>   you typically send it a
>   setObjectValue: message to restore a
>   saved predicate. NSPredicateEditor
>   needs to determine which of its
>   templates should display each
>   predicate in the predicate tree. It
>   does this by sending each of its row
>   templates a matchForPredicate: message
>   and choosing the one that returns the
>   highest value.
>
> After finding the best match for a
>   predicate, NSPredicateEditor copies
>   that template to get fresh views,
>   inserts them into the proper row, and
>   then sets the predicate on the
>   template using setPredicate:. Within
>   that method, the
>   NSPredicateEditorRowTemplate object
>   must set its views' values to
>   represent that predicate.
>
> NSPredicateEditorRowTemplate next asks
>   the template for the “displayable
>   sub-predicates” of the predicate by
>   sending a
>   displayableSubpredicatesOfPredicate:
>   message. If a template represents a
>   predicate in its entirety, or if the
>   predicate has no subpredicates, it can
>   return nil for this.  Otherwise, it
>   should return a list of predicates to
>   be made into sub-rows of that
>   template's row. The whole process
>   repeats for each sub-predicate.

Comment: Edited the question with more information regarding this suggestion.

Comment: Poking around Google, there seem to be one or two quirks with `NSPredicateEditor`, but I can't find any that would cause the editor to completely ignore `-setObjectValue:`.

Comment: @John (after edit): I might be an issue. I just dropped an NSPredicateEditor from the IB Library into the window and wired it up to the MyDocument File's Owner.  Do I need to do anything special with the NSPredicateEditorRowTemplates, or should the default ones work?

Comment: You will probably need to give it some `NSPredicateEditorRowTemplates`, but you should be able to do that in Interface Builder.

Comment: I found what's going on!  When I open a document (archived predicate) and attempt to read it, the nib hasn't been loaded yet.  I delayed setting the editor's objectValue until the nib was loaded, and then it worked perfectly.  Thanks for your help, John!